# Oracle Using Variable in DML data fetch?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying the following:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    V_COUNT NUMBER := 1;
    V_LIITM NUMBER := 1;
    V_LIMCU CHAR(12) := NULL;
    V_LILOCN CHAR(20) := NULL;
    V_LILOTN CHAR(30) := NULL;

BEGIN

    -- INITIAL COUNT --
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM QADTA.F41021
        where exists (select IBGLPT FROM QADTA.F4102
            where ibitm = liitm and ibmcu = LIMCU
            and ibglpt <> liglpt AND (LIPBIN = 'P' OR LIPQOH != 0));

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are initially '||V_COUNT||' missing registries.');

    -- GENERATING SEARCH VARIABLES --  
    SELECT LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN, LIGLPT
        INTO V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN, V_LIGLPT
        FROM QADTA.F41021 where exists (select IBGLPT FROM QADTA.F4102
            where ibitm = liitm and ibmcu = LIMCU and ibglpt <> liglpt
            AND (LIPBIN = 'P' OR LIPQOH != 0)) AND ROWNUM <= 1;

-- FIRST EXERCISE -- INSERT --
    INSERT INTO QADTA.F41021_BACKOUT
        SELECT LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN, LIGLPT FROM QADTA.F41021
            WHERE (LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN)
                IN (V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN);

-- SECOND EXERCISE -- UPDATE --
    UPDATE QADTA.F41021 
        SET F41021.LIGLPT = (SELECT IBGLPT FROM QADTA.F4102
            WHERE IBITM = LIITM and IBMCU = LIMCU)
            WHERE (LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN)
                IN (V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN);

    END;
```

However, when executing I get error "00920 - Invalid Relational Operators". I nullified the DML sentences & it worked, but I need to do data modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `IN` operator you can check if a list of expressions exists in another list of expressions. So if you use multiple expressions to the left of the operator, you also have to use multiple expressions on the right side.

In your example you will try to compare 4 values `LIITM`, `LIMCU`, `LILOCN`, `LILOTN` with the values `V_LIITM`, `V_LIMCU`, `V_LILOCN`, `V_LILOTN`.

For it to work, you have to make a group of elements by putting them in parentheses.`(V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN)`.

```
WHERE (LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN)
   IN ((V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN)
      , (V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN));
```

Without the parentheses, Oracle interprets the four values `V_LIITM`, `V_LIMCU`, `V_LILOCN`, `V_LILOTN` as a list of elements, and they do not match to the expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
WHERE (LIITM, LIMCU, LILOCN, LILOTN)
   IN (V_LIITM, V_LIMCU, V_LILOCN, V_LILOTN);
```

Have a look at an example:

```
SQL> create table x as select * From dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> insert into x
  2  select * from dept
  3  where (deptno, dname) in (10, 'ACCOUNTING');
where (deptno, dname) in (10, 'ACCOUNTING')
                         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator


SQL> insert into x
  2  select * from dept
  3  where deptno = 10
  4    and dname = 'ACCOUNTING';

1 row created.

SQL>
```

I guess you see what you have to do in order to fix it.

Also, while *generating search variables*, you're selecting `into V_LIGLPT` which is not declared.

Furthermore, I'd suggest you to use table aliases and qualify all columns in all queries with those aliases, so that it is clear which column belongs to which table.

Finally, when `INSERTING INTO`, name all target columns - don't rely on the fact that you "know" description of the target table, as it may (and some day it will) change.

Comment: His attempt is not entirely wrong. what he does is already possible. he just forgot the braces around the tuple

Comment: I tried it & it was successful, but why I can't use they “IN” operator?

Comment: Apparently, you can - but using the syntax hotfix provided.